# Best video streaming option for Android/iOS AWS

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to figure out what my best option is for streaming many videos to an Android/iOS app from an AWS S3 bucket.

My understanding right now is that it's possible to stream directly from the S3 bucket, but this is not recommended. I've looked into using AWS CloudFront to stream, but it looks as though each distribution that I create has to have a static source file to stream. This is an issue for me since the file that I want to stream will change frequently, so I dont have time to create a new distribution for every video that needs to be played.

Ideally I'd be able to set something up on the client side that requests a video stream given a url or object ID, and the server side just serves it right up. Is there a recommended way to do this with AWS? Or is there some other option that I have not thought of or come across yet?

The best scenario would be to use CloudFront, but be able to specify a file to stream at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use AWS CloudFront Distribution.There are three kinds of Video Streaming solution in AWS CloudFront Distribution.

1. [Microsoft Smooth Streaming](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/on-demand-streaming-smooth.html)
2. [HLS Stream](https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/delivering-hls-with-amazon-cloudfront/)
3. [RTMP Stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html)

If there are something not understandable, please tell me.